# Could somebody please explain to me how this binary relation is Anti-symmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

> $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ where $xRy$ if $x \mid y$
>
> $R = \{(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 2), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 4)\}$.

I am watching this video about Partial Orders and the guy just said the relation was Anti-symmetric; however, I do not understand why.

I know that for a relation to be anti-symmetric : if $aRb$ and $bRa$ then $a = b$.

However, I do not see that there. Sorry for not giving in more knowledge. I am just really confused on this one.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it useful to take the definition of "anti-symmetric" and use it to say under what conditions a relation $R$ is **not** anti-symmetric.  You'll find that for $R$ not to be anti-symmetric means that there exist $a$ and $b$ such that $aRb$ and $bRa$ but $a\neq b$.  Now look at the relation $R$ exhibited in the question and see whether you can find any such $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $xRy$ and $yRx$, with $x,y\ge0$. Then $x$ is a factor of $y$, and $y$ is a factor of $x$. These imply, respectively, that $x\le y$ and $y\le x$. It is clear to deduce from this that $x=y$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \mid y$ stand for "$x$ evenly divides $y$."  If $x \mid y$ and $y \mid x$ then $x=y$.  Hence, the divisibility relation is antisymmetric.  (It is indeed a partial order.)

The fact that for *non-negative* integers $x \mid y$ and $y \mid x$ imply that $x=y$ is not surprising, but if you want a full proof, consider this: $x$ evenly divides $y$ if there exists a non-negative integer $n$ such that $y = nx$.  Likewise, if $y$ evenly divides $x$, then there exists a non-negative integer $m$ such that $x = my$.

If both conditions are true, consider two cases.  If $x=0$, then $y = n0 = 0$.  Otherwise, substitution gives you $x = mnx$, and dividing both sides by $x$ (which we can, because we are now assuming that it is non-zero), we get $1 = mn$.  The only solution for $m,n$ nonnegative integers is $m=n=1$, which finally gives $x=y$.

Note that assuming that the integers are non-negative is important.  Otherwise, $-3$ divides $3$ and vice versa, but $-3 \neq 3$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a|b$ and $b|a$ then integers $k,\,l$ exist with $b=ka,\,a=lb=lka$. Since $a,\,b\in\left\{ 1,\,2,\,3,\,4\right\}$, we have $k,\,l>0$ and $lk=1$. Hence $k=l=1$ and $a=b$.

Comment: But what about (1,2) (1,3) ... 2 doesn't divide 1 and 3 doesn't divide 1. What do I do with those?

Comment: @RayRutzer In those cases $\left(a,\,b\right)\in R$ but $\left(b,\,a\right)\notin R$ (if I'm remembering $R$'s definition correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Use the contrapositive way of thinking about antisymmetry: $$aRb \text{ and  }bRa \implies a = b$$ is equivalent to $$a \neq b \implies \text{not} (aRb \text{ and } bRa);$$ in other words, you never see *both* $aRb$ and $bRa$ (or, as ordered pairs, both $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$) for distinct $a, b$. You don't even need to recognize that it's a divisibility relation; you can just **look** at it!

Comment: But what about (1,1), (2,2) ... wouldn't that violate that clause?

Comment: No, because $1 \neq 1$ is false (as is $2 \neq 2$). Remember: The contrapositive lets us think about pairs $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$ where $a \neq b$.

Comment: But if the left hand side is false doesn't that means that the entire statement is true in this case?

Comment: Right! So whenever $a = b$, the statement $$a \neq b \implies \text{not} (aRb \text{ and } bRa)$$ is true, and that statement is equivalent to the "usual" definition of antisymmetry. So the presence of pairs $(a, a)$ doesn't "violate" antisymmetry, even when formulated in this contrapositive way.

Comment: So the "working definition" that I like for antisymmetry is this: If $a \neq b$ and $aRb$, then it is not the case that $bRa$; or, as ordered pairs, when $a \neq b$ and $(a, b) \in R$, then $(b, a) \not\in R$. It just lets you scan relations (given as sets!) quickly to determine if there are any "symmetric" pairs (if there are any, your relation is **not** antisymmetric; if there aren't any, it is). It's just the most intuitive formulation for antisymmetry in general, for me.

Comment: If I am understanding right, anti-simmetry holds because there are not (2,1) , (3,1) , etc therefore aRb and bRa a=b because in the only case they are equal is in reflexivity a=a. Thus, if a not = b  then not ( aRb and bRa). As long as those are absent AKA (1,2) with (2,1) and (1,3) with (3,1) ... we can assume the relation is anti-simmetric ?

Comment: Please just confirm it or tell me if I am wrong. Your answer is the most helpful one so far :) At least for me to understand it.

Comment: @Ray Yes, that's correct, very nice! Once we see a pair like $(1,2)$, we'd better not see $(2,1)$ for it to be antisymmetric. Since this is the case, that there are no pairs of pairs like this, it must be antisymmetric. (So it's not *assuming* that it's not antisymmetric; we've *verified* it).